# Difference between declaring variables inside or outside of constructor?

Tags: php

For example is there a difference between the two?  Is one preferred to the other?

```
Class Node{    
    public $parent = null;
    public $right = null;
    public $left = null;            
    function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;                    
    }
}

Class Node{     
    function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;      
        $this->parent = null;       
        $this->left = null;       
        $this->right = null;               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are certain differences, yes:

**#1: The class is not formally considered to have these properties if you only define them in the constructor**

[Example](http://ideone.com/H1y562):

```
class Foo {
    public $prop = null;
}

class Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->prop = null;
    }
}

var_dump(property_exists('Foo', 'prop')); // true
var_dump(property_exists('Bar', 'prop')); // false

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

var_dump(property_exists($foo, 'prop')); // true
var_dump(property_exists($bar, 'prop')); // true
```

In addition to the different runtime behavior, it is bad form to use the constructor to "add" properties to your class. If you intend *all* objects of this class to have the property (which should be practically all of the time) then you should also formally declare them. The fact that PHP allows you to get away with this does not excuse the haphazard class design.

**#2: You cannot initialize properties to non-constant values from outside the constructor**

Example:

```
class Foo {
    public $prop = 'concatenated'.'strings'; // does not compile
}
```

[More examples](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-172) regarding this constraint are provided in the PHP manual.

**#3: For values initialized inside the constructor, if a derived class omits calling the parent constructor the result might be unexpected**

[Example](http://ideone.com/U5ypVe):

```
class Base {
    public $alwaysSet = 1;
    public $notAlwaysSet;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->notAlwaysSet = 1;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public function __construct() {
        // do not call parent::__construct()
    }
}

$d = new Derived;
var_dump($d->alwaysSet); // 1
var_dump($d->notAlwaysSet); // NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I really appreciate all your code samples as well as the links to the php notepads

Answer (score 1):

I prefer declaring them outside of my constructor for several reasons.

1. to keep my constructors clean
2. so I can properly document them, adding type information and the likes
3. so I can specify access modifiers, making them either private or protected, but rarely if ever public
4. so they will also be declared and/or initialized if a derived class doesn't call parent::__construct()

Even if I need to initialize them to a non-constant value, I will declare them outside my constructor and initialize them in my constructor.